# WiX Define used in directory specification

Tags: wix

I'm trying to use a 'define' in a directory name on wix 3.11.

I've tried less-complex forms of the define, 
like trying with the define as AppName="My App 2019", (without the nested AppYear).

and I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong, and how do I accomplish this?

```
<?Define AppYear="2019"?>
<?Define AppName="My App $(var.AppYear)"?>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)" >
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.SolutionName)" >
        <Directory Id="APPDIR" Name="Application Files" >
          <Directory Id="APPSUBDIR" Name="$(var.AppName)" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I get the following compiler error when compiling:

Error Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.AppName)'.

Comment: It should be `<?define AppName="My App $(var.AppYear)"?>` (lower case `define`).

Comment: @zett42 Maybe add as an answer?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul No, see close vote.

Comment: Thanks @zett42 !  That was the problem!  WiX sometimes makes me crazy.